# Названия эффектов?

Tags: jquery, css, css3, css-animation

Гуглю , но не нахожу.
Подскажите , как называются эффекты ?

1. При наведении на картинку её размеры не увеличиваются , но происходит как будто её приближение , плавный zoom какой то.
2. Во время скролла прилетают блоки и появляется текст.

Comment: первый как я понимаю `transform:scale` второй `tranform:translate` и все это применяется с `transform:transition` для плавности.... а в целом это может быть css анимация

Comment: @Vipz, данные эффекты называются, `mouseleave` (более предыдущий вариант, `mouseover`). - это касается событий при наведении мышки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. transform: scale
2. wow.js + animate.css

Answer (score 2):

1. [transition](https://html5book.ru/css3-transition/)
2. Необходимо [подключить js](https://css-tricks.com/aos-css-driven-scroll-animation-library/)

Comment: зачем  необходимо подключить js?

Comment: чтобы при определенной позиции скролла у нас появлялся какой-нибудь блок, думаю, что на одном css не получится это сделать

Comment: Пожалуйста, перенесите пример из статьи прямо в ответ

Answer (score 0):

вот вам приближение при наведении

```css
#wrapperFoto {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#foto {
    position: absolute;
    width: 700px;
    height: 450px;
    background: url(https://s1.1zoom.ru/b5050/929/289494-alexfas01_1920x1200.jpg
    );
    background-size: cover;
    transition: all .3s;
}

#wrapperFoto:hover #foto {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapperFoto">
  <div id="foto"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Поддерживаю ответы с примерами )

Answer (score 0):

1. `transform:scale(1.1);` в блоке с одинаковой высотой и `overflow:hidden;`.
2. *Wow.js* + *animate.css* (для *wow.js* *JQuery* не нужен)

Я бы сейчас привел пример, да компьютера под рукой нет.