# Увеличение фона у дива при наведении

Tags: html, css

У меня 3 дива, у них фон, надо сделать так чтобы див при наведении не увеличивался а фон в нем увеличивался.
http://sitehero.us/

```
.img-wr {
    text-align: center;
}
.img-wr1,
.img-wr2,
.img-wr3 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32%;
    height: 240px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img-wr1 {
    background-image: url("http://sitehero.us/image/catalog/banerside1.png");
}
.img-wr2 {
    background-image: url("http://sitehero.us/image/catalog/bannermiddle.png");
}
.img-wr3 {
    background-image: url("http://sitehero.us/image/catalog/banner31.png");
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никак вы этого не сделаете, пока не разделите фон и текст на нем

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Названия эффектов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/696902/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d1%84%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: пожалуйста, тоже самое и все работает https://shop-mining.com/

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать псевдокласс `:hover` и свойство `background-size`:

```
.img-wr1:hover { /*то же самое для wr2 и wr3*/
    background-size: 150%;
}
```

Только с текстом что-то нужно сделать, а то он вшит в фон и вместе с ним увеличивается, чего, я так понимаю, не надо.

Comment: Все это я делал, это очевидно. суть в "див при наведении не увеличивался а фон в нем увеличивался"

Comment: @Alex2222 А в моём варианте разве не так?

Comment: Забыл сказать, почему мне не понравилось, я это первым делом сделал, только увеличение происходит моментально, а транситион не работает

Answer (score 1):

Это осуществляется при помощи `transform: scale(1.2);` на дочернем элементе (у которого есть бэкграунд). [Здесь](https://css-tricks.com/zooming-background-images/) есть подробная инструкция.

Comment: Только надо в данном диве создать ещё один див с этим самым фоном

Comment: @Byulent, всё верно. В статье это описано.

Comment: @Alex2222, да, будет контейнер, который будет отлавливать hover или focus события и будет дочерний элемент внутри него, который будет по этим событиям увеличиваться, но то, что вылезет за рамки родителя, скрыто overflow`ом.

Comment: но там высота и ширина у контейнера, я могу ее не задавать? мне же адаптировать надо это дело

Comment: Какой толк если оно не адаптивно...